# I want to make a loop by using iterator way, but there is an error

Tags: c++, qt, iterator, qlist, qtreewidgetitem

I have the following code:

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> selectedItems = ui->treeWidget->selectedItems();
for(QList<QTreeWidgetItem>::iterator i = selectedItems.begin(); i != selectedItems.end(); i++){
    qDebug() << i;  
}
```

But there is an error:
`conversion from 'QList<QTreeWidgetItem*>::iterator' to non-scalar type 'QList<QTreeWidgetItem>::iterator' requested`

Comment: try `QList<QTreeWidgetItem *>::iterator i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `QList<QTreeWidgetItem *>::iterator` ?

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried to use `QList<QTreeWidgetItem *>`, but I forgot to change `qDebug() << i;`  to `qDebug() << *i;`. I have lost my focus.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to contain different types referred, namely:

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> selectedItems = ui->treeWidget->selectedItems();
                      ^    

for(QList<QTreeWidgetItem>::iterator i = selectedItems.begin(); i != selectedItems.end(); i++)
                        ^
```

You can see that you use pointer in the former case, but not the latter. This is also what the compiler is trying to write to you. You will need two changes to address this issue:

```
for (QList<QTreeWidgetItem*>::iterator i = selectedItems.begin(); i != selectedItems.end(); ++i)
 //                      ^
    qDebug() << *i; // Need to change to dereference, respectively
```

You could just as well use the foreach construction as follows as it is slightly shorter to write and comprehend:

```
foreach (QTreeWidgetItem* item, selectedItems)
    qDebug() << item;
```